# Circuit heating

Tags: arduino, batteries, lipo

I am using 14.8 Volts 21Ah Lithium ion battery to control a circuit.
The circuit consists of a controller, LM2596 buck converter (set to 5.5 Volts), 5v relay driver , 5v electromagnectic relays,  and DC Johnson geared motors ( 4  to 8 Johnson geared DC motors connected in parallel).
When I connect all together everything works fine for a few minutes but then after some time the complete circuit gets fully heated.

After sometime the circuit stops working.

If I remove the motors and try to check operation without load then the relay gets activated and works properly. But If I connect load a DC motor then the working of the circuit will be normal. If I connect many motors then gradually Relay, Circuit all components , buck converter everything gets heated up.

Any advice on possible causes of the overheating and ways to reduce it to an acceptable level would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show a schematic, and ask a question, this is a Q&A Site

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Your advice re a schematic is good. Your comment on 'asking a question' may have some merit once a newcomer gets used to the site but, unless you can speak Bengali as well as he speaks English (which is rather well) then it's arguably politer to leave such advice out for now OR put it in a positive and encouraging way. This is a be-nice zone. (Did you see what I did there?)(Don't you hate that expression ? :-) ).

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't even look at the name plate when I wrote that. I do think that I was nice however, I did ask please, which is nice.

Answer (score 2):

The LM2596 is a 3A regulator. At max load it is 73% efficient, which is kind of low for a DC-DC, so it will be shedding 4W between the regulator and other losses. That’s a tremendous amount of heat, so the regulator is going into thermal shutdown to protect itself.

What is the load for each motor? I could easily imagine that with a large number of them, likely you are exceeding what that regulator can do.

Consider breaking up your circuit to use multiple DC-DC converters for the multiple relays and motor sets.